# Restrict other users from joining telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Suppose I created a telegram bot with the following info;

```
botname: name11
username: user22
bot_token: XXXX
chat_id: YYYYY
```

I want to restrict other users from joining. Only myself (username: `myself`) can join. Can this be done in telegram?

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such settings or functionality in Telegram bots(yet).
You can put a simple checking in the first line of your handlers and only respond to the authorized UserIDs.